# AudioQueueStart slowly

Tags: iphone, audio-recording

I am now in developing a voice applications, the need for frequent start recording device, but every time AudioQueueStart need 0.3 s, I see the apple of the sample: speakhere, it started recording also need such a long time. Is there a way to turn every start recording time shorten? Who can help me?

Comment: what's your buffer size?

Answer (score 0):

A similar question was asked here: [Delay when using AudioQueueStart()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066627/delay-when-using-audioqueuestart)

Seems like there's no way around it than to use another library. The details are in the first section of this [blog post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066627/delay-when-using-audioqueuestart).